# Connecting "paths" of a network of points into "routes"

Tags: algorithm, matlab, networking, routes, nodes

I have a matrix called `paths`.

```
paths =  1 2
         1 3
         1 4
         2 3
         2 5
         3 4
         3 5
```

Each element is the index of a 2D coordinate in matrix `Crdnts`. Each row of `paths` indicates that the two points in the row are connected by a "path".

For example, as indicated by the first row, `Crdnts(1,:)` is connected to `Crdnts(2,:)`.

I want to create a matrix called `routes` that connects all of the paths into "routes" (starting from point 1)

Using the `paths` matrix above, `routes` would be

```
routes = 1 2 3 4
         1 2 3 5
         1 2 5 *
         1 3 4 *
         1 3 5 *
         1 4 * *
```

A few issues I should point out:

1. Usually there are about 1000 coordinates in `Crdnts`.
2. Routes can have different sizes (see example *). Some may have 100 paths, some only 1. A cell array might be better than a matrix for this reason.

I'm looking for a way to do this without using too many for loops as this takes a lot of time with many points/paths. I have no intention of finding a "shortest route" etc. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Here is a link to the Matlab source code (using the above example): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qcxjephx8bpo01z/PlcokTuORG. 

"pathsproblem" is the main script file. "find_routes" is a custom function.

It's not beautiful, but it works and it's fairly readable. It's very quick for relatively few paths but gets slow for paths > 100,000 or so. I can do some speed tests if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Section 6.1 of Algorithm Design by Kleinberg, Tardos describes the interval scheduling problem which is equivalent to this one.